# Flutter: find item in list of maps and update it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 nested collections (portfolios, rents and leases) and I get the last one like this:

```
getRentLeases() {
    final portfolio = list.where((portfolio) {
      return portfolio['documentID'].contains(currentPortfolioId)
          ? true
          : false;
    }).toList();
    final rent = portfolio[0]['rents'].where((rent) {
      return rent['documentID'].contains(currentRentId) ? true : false;
    }).toList();
    return rent[0]['leases'];
  }
```

as you see I always have the ID for previous collection saved.

To find a specific lease I could follow similar approach:

```
var lease = getRentLeases().where((lease) {
      return lease['documentID'].contains(newLease['documentID'])
          ? true
          : false;
    }).toList();
```

but how could I update it? Something like this doesn't work:

```
lease = newLease;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `? true : false` is not necessary as `contains` already gives you a boolean value.
2. If you only expect one item to be returned by the `where` method, then you should go for `singleWhere` as it directly gives you the item instead of the list. If none of these or multiple items satisfy the condition, you get an exception.
3. You should separate getRentLeases into two methods. In this case its even better to have methods returning the index of the relevant item.
   Please consider that I only used `dynamic` because I don't have access to the data types. You should instead type the variables.

Code:

```
int getIndexOfPortFolio(String portfolioId) {
  return list
  .indexWhere(portfolio => portfolio['documentID'].contains(portfolioId));
}

int getIndexOfRent(dynamic portfolio, String rentId) {
  return portfolio['rents']
  .indexWhere(rent => rent['documentID'].toString().contains(rentId));
}

int getIndexOfLease(dynamic rent, String leaseId) {
  return rent['leases']
  .indexWhere(lease => lease['documentID'].toString().contains(leaseId));
}
```

And then you can update your object like this:

```
void updateLease(String portfolioId, String rentId, String oldLeaseId, dynamic newLease) {
  int portFolioIndex = getIndexOfPortFolio(portfolioId);
  var portFolio = list[portFolioIndex];
  int rentIndex = getIndexOfRent(portFolio, rentId);
  var rent = portFolio["rents"][rentIndex];
  int leaseIndex = getIndexOfLease(rent, oldLeaseId);
  rent["leases"][leaseIndex] = newLease;
}
```

Comment: I returned true/false because I was getting this error: "dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test'". That fixed it.
Getting the index was what I had on my mind. I thought that maybe was possible to update that directly from the where but if not I guess I should take that approach

Comment: that example is giving me previous error

Comment: You can avoid a lot of errors by typing the variables. What do you mean with "previous error"? Post the full error message. I don't know how `portfolio` is structured so you should provide the structure and maybe dummy data for validation.

Comment: I just removed the types from the indexWhere and it worked